# How can I modify my four quadrants to allow some "breathing room" between them (HTML/CSS)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, padding

I have been able to create four equi-sized/shaped quadrants on my page based on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855483/how-can-i-force-each-piece-of-a-quadrant-to-inhabit-only-its-fourth-of-the-area).

So the page now looks like so:

[image]

I want to now give the quadrants some "elbow room" - some blank space around their edges. I tried adding margin to the classes they use:

```
.topleft {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 4;
}
.topright {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 4;
}
.bottomleft {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 4;
}
.bottomright {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 4;
}
```

That did nothing; I tried then adding padding:

```
.topleft {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 4;
}
.topright {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 4;
}
.bottomleft {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 4;
}
.bottomright {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 4;
}
```

...and that also did nothing.

What do I need to do to keep the same 1/4 space for all, but effectively "squish" them a scosh by adding margin between them or padding around them?

Here is the entire html/css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>eServices Customer Dashboard</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<!-- Inline CSS (don't tell the CSS-Whisperers I did this!) -->
<style>
body {
    background-color: azure;
}
.body-content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 #000000;
    box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
   padding-left: 1px;
   padding-right: 1px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.jumbotronjr {
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: white;
}
.addltopmargin {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.sectiontext {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
}
.bottommarginbreathingroom {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.marginaboveandbelow {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.rightjustifytext {
  text-align: right;
}
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
.contents{
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
}
redfont {
    color: red;
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.topleft {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 4;
}
.topright {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 4;
}
.bottomleft {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 4;
}
.bottomright {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 4;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="contents">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 topleft">
<h2>Top 10 Items Purchased</h2>
        <div>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangefrom2" name="daterangefrom2">
            </input>
            <label> to </label>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangeto2" name="daterangeto2">
            </input>
        </div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Item Code 1</td>
                <td>Description 1</td>
                <td>Qty 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item Code 2</td>
                <td>Description 2</td>
                <td>Qty 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item Code 3</td>
                <td>Description 3</td>
                <td>Qty 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item Code 4</td>
                <td>Description 4</td>
                <td>Qty 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item Code 5</td>
                <td>Description 5</td>
                <td>Qty 5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item Code 6</td>
                <td>Description 6</td>
                <td>Qty 6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item Code 7</td>
                <td>Description 7</td>
                <td>Qty 7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item Code 8</td>
                <td>Description 8</td>
                <td>Qty 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item Code 9</td>
                <td>Description 9</td>
                <td>Qty 9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item Code 10</td>
                <td>Description 10</td>
                <td>Qty 10</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 topright">
<h2>Pricing Exceptions - Weekly Recap</h2>
<h3 class="redfont">Red denotes Contract Item Overages</h3>
<h3>For Weyand on the pricing week of - 7/31/2016</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Invoice No</th>
                <th>Invoice Date</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Cust #</th>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Member Item Code</th>
                <th>Member Description</th>
                <th>Bid Price</th>
                <th>Sell Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Inv No 1</td>
                <td>Inv Date 1</td>
                <td>Customer 1</td>
                <td>Cust # 1</td>
                <td>Item Code 1</td>
                <td>Descrip. 1</td>
                <td>M.I. Code 1</td>
                <td>Memb Desc 1</td>
                <td>Bid Price 1</td>
                <td>Sell Pr. 1</td>
                <td>Qty 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Inv No 2</td>
                <td>Inv Date 2</td>
                <td>Customer 2</td>
                <td>Cust # 2</td>
                <td>Item Code 2</td>
                <td>Descrip. 2</td>
                <td>M.I. Code 2</td>
                <td>Memb Desc 2</td>
                <td>Bid Price 2</td>
                <td>Sell Pr. 2</td>
                <td>Qty 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Inv No 3</td>
                <td>Inv Date 3</td>
                <td>Customer 3</td>
                <td>Cust # 3</td>
                <td>Item Code 3</td>
                <td>Descrip. 3</td>
                <td>M.I. Code 3</td>
                <td>Memb Desc 3</td>
                <td>Bid Price 3</td>
                <td>Sell Pr. 3</td>
                <td>Qty 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 bottomleft">
<h2>Forecasted Spend</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Last Week's Usage</th>
                <th>This Week's Price</th>
                <th>Forecasted Spend</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Item 1</td>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>TWP 1</td>
                <td>68.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item 2</td>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>TWP 2</td>
                <td>65.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item 3</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>TWP 3</td>
                <td>63.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item 4</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>TWP 4</td>
                <td>60.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item 5</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>TWP 5</td>
                <td>58.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item 6</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>TWP 6</td>
                <td>60.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item 7</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>TWP 7</td>
                <td>61.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item 8</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>TWP 8</td>
                <td>61.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TOTAL</td>
                <td>314</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>$496.00</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-6 bottomright">
<h2>Fill Rate</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Co. Name</th>
                <th>Desc</th>
                <th>Ord</th>
                <th>Ship</th>
                <th>Var</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Unit 1</td>
                <td>Co. Name 1</td>
                <td>Desc 1</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit 2</td>
                <td>Co. Name 2</td>
                <td>Desc 2</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit 3</td>
                <td>Co. Name 3</td>
                <td>Desc 3</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit 4</td>
                <td>Co. Name 4</td>
                <td>Desc 4</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit 5</td>
                <td>Co. Name 5</td>
                <td>Desc 5</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit 6</td>
                <td>Co. Name 6</td>
                <td>Desc 6</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit 7</td>
                <td>Co. Name 7</td>
                <td>Desc 7</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit 8</td>
                <td>Co. Name 8</td>
                <td>Desc 8</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TOTAL</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>280</td>
                <td>279</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### UPDATE

Adding padding just has the appearance of bloating the quadrants, not providing any breathing room between them. It looks more or less as if a "top" property was assigned to the first element, pushing it further down.

Adding margin (16px) causes the quadrants to line up vertically on the page - all on the left, nothing on the right. The four pieces are stacked vertically, each one atop the next.

Comment: *some blank space around their edges* - Do you want that space to be the same color as your quadrants (padding) or do you want actual white space between them (margin). Because simply adding a margin there breaks things. I think the answers below are all ignoring the fact that you're using Bootstrap's grid layout.

Comment: White space; yes, I think you're right, as my Update shows that neither padding nor margin works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add new classes to the divs containing the bootstrap `column` classes. Instead, create a child div and apply your styles to the inner div.

For example:
Replace

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 topleft">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

with

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="topleft">
        ...
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you're controlling the overall boundary of the container in the outer div and styling it (adding margins, padding) in the inner div.

Also, use px/em units for padding/margin as others suggested.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKQwyg

Answer (score 3):

Both `margin` and `padding` take CSS **length** units. There's a lot of different ones as they classify in absolute units (pixels or `px` being the most common) or relative ones (`em`, `rem` being the most common). You may also use a dimension value which is given by percentages `%` even though is not a length value.

For the full list and an in-depth explanation please refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length).

In your case probably `padding` will help you out, and you may want to use a bigger value than `4px`.

Comment: padding does not produce the effect I want - the four quadrants are still just as tightly conjoined as ever.

Comment: Add a wrapper div containing the content of every `col-md-6` and attach the padding to it instead of applying the padding directly to every column. That way it will work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Give the unit of `margin` & `padding` property like `px, em`. Try giving `margin: 4px;`. But `4px` seem very small.

Comment: try giving `margin: 4px;`. But `4px` seem very small. 

Yeah set your margins a little larger, or huge just to make sure they are being applied. You need to have px or % to have the effect, which your code is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unit to your margin / padding, such as px (absolute) or em (relative). Please refer to this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp